# Would bitcoin core work on a big endian system? Or even a system where C++'s `int` is not 32-bit?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, development, network, full-node

Looking at the source code of bitcoin core, [the serialization part](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/serialize.h#L195), I see that there's no serialization abstraction layer that accounts for a possible different endianness or different binary layouts on different machines.

This is not only for disk serialization, but also for network serialization. 
If bitcoin core was used on a big-endian machine, or a machine with `int` size not equal to 32-bit, it'll fail to connect to the network because all sizes will be incorrectly interpreted and values will be different.

Am I missing something or did I arrive at the correct conclusion?

Comment: The byteswap has been addressed in MCCCS's answer (it's done by `htole16` and the like).  For the word size, can you explain specifically what you think is wrong?  That code appears, at first glance, to make proper use of the `uintNN_t` types.

Comment: @NateEldredge Many of the data structures being serialized use int/long/short/..., and serialize those directly. The serialization code per se does the right thing, but the data being serialized wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ser_writedata8` does not care about endianness, in contrast to `ser_writedata16`, `ser_writedata32`, `ser_writedata64`. Single bytes don't need to swapped, as [8 bits have one address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803397/can-endianness-refer-to-bits-order-in-a-byte) and there's no way to access specific bits without using BMI or arithmetic operations. Therefore, bit endianness is not important except in [bitfields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804571/6557621).

Comment: I know 1 byte doesn't need endianness flips. I just couldn't see how the flipping is being done.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist For example, `Serialize(Stream& s, uint16_t a)` calls `ser_writedata16`, which calls `htole16(obj);`. `htole16` does the bswap there.

Answer (score 2):

It should work on big-endian systems. The serialization code for integers will byteswap on such systems. This was certainly tested at some point, but I'm not sure how recently someone has.

I don't think it will work on systems where int is different than 32-bit.